# Given stream is not seekable In FPDI

Tags: php, codeigniter, pdf, fpdi

I am using FPDI library to merge multiple pdf files into one,

followed this documentaion https://manuals.setasign.com/fpdi-manual/v2/the-fpdi-class/

I have tried like below,

```
use \setasign\Fpdi\Fpdi;
use \setasign\Fpdi\PdfParser\StreamReader;
function merge()
{
    $file = fopen('https://path/to/s3/file','rb');
    $pdf = new Fpdi();
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pdf->setSourceFile(new  StreamReader($file));
    $tplIdx = $pdf->importPage(1);
    $pdf->useTemplate($tplIdx, 10, 10, 100);
    $pdf->SetFont('Helvetica');
    $pdf->SetTextColor(255, 0, 0);
    $pdf->SetXY(30, 30);
    $pdf->Write(0, 'This is just a simple text');
    $pdf->Output();
}
```

When tried to pass url in streamReader I am getting **Given stream is not seekable**.

How can I pass s3 file to stream reader and merge it.

Comment: Not exactly sure why you would need the Stream Reader. Have you tried the [default merger](https://manuals.setasign.com/setapdf-merger-manual/) and tried [these methods?](https://manuals.setasign.com/setapdf-merger-manual/add-files-or-documents/#index-2)

Comment: Hi @Jamie_D, I have used Stream Reader to read files from s3 bucket, **setSourceFile** takes only local path.

Comment: Assuming that your S3 pdf file is public, try `$file =Document  SetaPDF_Core_Document::loadByString(
    file_get_contents('https://path/to/s3/file')
);` See [example here](https://manuals.setasign.com/setapdf-merger-manual/add-files-or-documents/#index-2)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

An HTTP stream wrapper does not support seeking.

You have to download the bucket to a temporary file or variable. A simple `file_get_contents()` should do it:

```
$fileContent = file_get_contents('https://path/to/s3/file');
// ...
$pdf->setSourceFile(StreamReader::createByString($fileContent));
```

Comment: Hi, this works perfectly on my local machine but when hosting through AWS Lambda using Laravel Vapor, I get a 503 error. Any idea what the cause could be? Been battling with this for weeks now...

Comment: 503 means "Service Unavailable". Maybe [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/http-503-service-unavailable.html) will help you.

Comment: It workerd for me withou the 'rb' parameter.

Comment: @achasinh sure, I just removed it.

Answer (score 3):

For those who try to load the file from the same server (not apply to this case but could help others solve this error): change *http://example.com/path/file.pdf* to a local path like this */home/user/public_html/path/file.pdf*